# Extemporaneous access to the result of a method

Tags: c#

I need CallerMethod() to access a value found in CalledMethod(). 
String s is the result of the execution of other methods that are executed independently before.
The CallerMethod() method is not tied to the execution of CalledMethod().
The CallerMethod() and CalledMethod() methods belong to two different projects. It doesn't seem right to create a static class to store this value. What do you think is the best way?
The projects are Windows Form.

```
Public void PreviousMethod()
{
    CalledMethod(a);
}

Public void CalledMethod(string value)
{
    string s = value;
}

Public void CallerMethod()
{
    string getStringSFromCalledMethod = "?";
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to create a static class? Where is the value coming from? Is it a "magic value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to get into static variables. What you need is simply an Instance Property Member, to store the previously calculated value

```
class Class1 {
    public string ValueOfImportance { get; private set; }
    public void CalledMethod(string value) {
        ValueOfImportance = value; // possibly after processing the data from other calls
    }

}

class Class2 {
    public void CallerMethod() {
        Class1 obj; // you need to have the object reference of Class1
        string getStringSFromCalledMethod = obj.ValueOfImportance;
    }
}
```

When you generate the `ValueOfImportance`, you will need to make sure that the object reference is available to `Class2.CallerMethod()`